# Add-on plan not found While adding pg backups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres

I was trying to move my PG-Backup from local machine to Heroku,

But it fails saying that :-

`Rajat@RAJAT-PC /c/Sites/RajatSample (master)`
`$ heroku addons:add pgbackups`
`Your version of git is 1.9.4.. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.`
`More information here:`https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
Adding pgbackups on bungeeapp... failed
 !    Add-on plan not found....`

Some one can please help...I am new to RoR

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Pg Backups is deprecated. It is removed from addons. You can find more info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups)

Comment: So what should I ideally do for that as in my databases its saying that Snapshots

Heroku PG-Backups addon not attached

Comment: If I want to move the data from my local table to Heroku db table...!!
What should I do...??

Comment: Got It...!!
pg_dump file..:D...Will keep on asking if it doesnt get resolved :)

Comment: I am not aware of the process how you should be handling in ror but i believe if you go through heroku documentation you will find a solution.